Spin contamination in solid state
When dealing with quantum chemistry, many times a problem that one has to deal with it spin contamination. In many cases, ROKS is used instead of UDFT to avoid this problem.
Theoretically, when dealing with solid state calculations, spin-polarized (UDFT) calculations are performed, thus opening up the possibility of having spin contamination in the results. However, very few studies report this in periodic models. Why isn't ROKS more used in periodic cases and why isn't spin contamination more discussed in solid state?

I'm a bit more familiar with electronic structure theory of molecular systems than of condensed-phase systems. However, there's a lot of overlap in concepts and techniques especially in SCF and many-body methods.
The concept of spin in density functional approximations based on Kohn-Sham DFT can be ambiguous (see responses to this post). One formally needs information contained in the two-particle density matrix in order to resolve proper expectation values from a two-body spin operator (e.g. $\mathcal{S}^2$).
Nonetheless, KS-DFT is widely used in the computational modeling of periodic systems, for many good reasons. Ground-state, zero-temperature energetics should be quite valid if an extended system with an even number of electrons is well described by a spin-unpolarized (restricted) single determinant SCF solution. From my understanding, this scenario is typical with pristine crystals but not necessarily with defect sites, charged regions, or interfaces. Other experts here may have additional insight on this.
High-spin solutions from spin-polarized (unrestricted) calculations typically exhibit less spin contamination compared to low-spin, broken-symmetry solutions; this is often the case in gas-phase molecular systems and its likely that this trend is present in the condensed-phase as well. Analogous to molecular problems, unrestricted calculations for different up ($\alpha$) and down ($\beta$) spin band structures may be necessary to describe magnetic properties or bond dissociation.
In ROKS, one set of orbitals is used to optimize $2 E_{BS} - E_{T}$ where  $E_{BS}$ is the energy of the broken-symmetry singlet determinant (or deformed density) and $E_{T}$ is the triplet energy. This is of course meant to directly estimate the spin-pure singlet energy. In a related approach, approximate projection, the $E_{BS}$ and $E_{T}$ energies are computed separately with different orbitals. The assumption here is that only one higher-lying spin contaminant is mixing into the BS reference. Note that the spin correction scheme is a bit different when working with doublets (see https://doi.org/10.1063/1.3530801). When using AP with extended systems, careful attention is necessary in order to deal with issues of size consistency and choices of single-particle basis representations. Here are some other references analyzing such approaches that I find quite informative.
https://doi.org/10.1080/00268976.2017.1393573
https://doi.org/10.1063/1.475804
https://doi.org/10.1063/1.468265
https://iopscience.iop.org/article/10.7567/1882-0786/ab4a37
As an aside; these spin correction models, which can be applied to certain classes of both ground and excited state problems, are connected to the spin projection operator method for annihilating higher spin states from a low-spin reference (refer to Eq. 1-3 in https://doi.org/10.1080/00268976.2018.1554828).
For periodic systems, researchers have recently determined S^2 values with different methods and discuss spin contamination:
https://doi.org/10.1063/5.0054661
https://iopscience.iop.org/article/10.1088/2516-1075/ad48ed/
https://iopscience.iop.org/article/10.1088/1361-648X/ab0170/
As an example, in this excellent paper by Pokhilko & Zgid, expressions for $\langle \mathcal{S}^{2}\rangle$ are presented and deviations from $\langle \mathcal{S}^{2}\rangle_\mathrm{Exact}$ are examined for some metal-oxides. The value of $\langle \mathcal{S}^{2}\rangle_\mathrm{UHF}$ is shown to still be a good diagnostic for the total spin of the supersystem. Though $\langle \mathcal{S}^{2}\rangle_\mathrm{GW}$ may also exhibit some spin contamination, such errors that arise from this are reported to cancel out and provide useful estimates for magnetic couplings and difference-based quantities. It is not unsurprising that missing configurations needed for spin recoupling or perturbative post-SCF density/wavefunction corrections may allow $\langle \mathcal{S}^{2}\rangle$ to deviate in a "non-variational" kind of way. Still, post-SCF methods for periodic systems like GW or even coupled-cluster now are very robust and powerful provided one has a viable reference solution with a (mostly) well-designated total spin.
Apart from possible convergence difficulties, ROKS should be applicable to solids, if needed. Additionally, for periodic systems, the concept of local spin is demonstrably very useful as are certain charge-localization models.

thanks @quantumcat ! I have another question about something you cited here. I will post a separate one

IIRC there's a paper from the 1990s(?) that points out that ROKS should not be used, since it screws up a very basic property of DFT, which is the nuclear cusp condition...
